# XY Path Locked Controllable Character

Tags: unity-game-engine, path, character, controls, spline

I am currently working on a platformer game in Unity3D which would take place in a 3D environment with 2D controls (left, right, jump).

I have search the internet and tried a couple of different methods such as iTween, but wasn't satisfied with it.

What I am trying to create is a curved path/plane on which the player's X and Y positions would be locked to the path. The player would be able to walk back and forth on the path, just like any other platformer, the spline would only allow me to use the 3D environment better and show off an immersive world under different angles. Tthe Z axis, however, would be free, allowing the player to go as high or low as they'd want.

I am not exactly sure how to proceed and I was wondering if you guys had any advice or ideas on the best way to do it.

Thanks,
Septos

Comment: Please show your current attempts at solving this yourself

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, here is the code I have come up with so far:

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer, here is the code I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CharacterPathController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    enum Direction {Forward, Backward};
    Direction charDirection;

    public PathEditor pathToFollow;

    private Vector3 lastPos;
    private Vector3 charRotation;
    private Vector3 direction;

    public string pathName;
    public int currentWayPointID = 0;
    public float speed;
    public float rotationSpeed = 7f;

    private float reachDistance = 1.0f;
    private float distanceX;
    private float distanceZ;

    void Start ()
    {
        //pathToFollow = GameObject.Find(pathName).GetComponent<PathEditor>();
        lastPos = transform.position;
    }

    void Update () 
    {
        Movement();
    }

    void Movement()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            charDirection = Direction.Forward;

            //Calculates distance between target x and z position and object's
            if(pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.x > transform.position.x)
                distanceX = pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.x - transform.position.x;
            else
                distanceX = transform.position.x - pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.x;

            if(pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.z > transform.position.z)
                distanceZ = pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.z - transform.position.z;
            else
                distanceZ = transform.position.z - pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.z;

            //Lerps object's x and z to target's
            lastPos.x = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.x, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            lastPos.z = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.z, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            transform.position = new Vector3(lastPos.x, 0, lastPos.z);

            //Get target's position and rotates on y-axis
            Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.x, 
                                                 this.transform.position.y, 
                                                 pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID].position.z);
            this.transform.LookAt(targetPosition);

            if(distanceX <= reachDistance && distanceZ <= reachDistance)
                currentWayPointID++;
        }
        else if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            charDirection = Direction.Backward;

            //Calculates distance between target x and z position and object's
            if(pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.x > transform.position.x)
                distanceX = pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.x - transform.position.x;
            else
                distanceX = transform.position.x - pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.x;

            if(pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.z > transform.position.z)
                distanceZ = pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.z - transform.position.z;
            else
                distanceZ = transform.position.z - pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.z;

            //Lerps object's x and z to target's
            lastPos.x = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.x, pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.x, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            lastPos.z = Mathf.Lerp(transform.position.z, pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.z, Time.deltaTime * speed);
            transform.position = new Vector3(lastPos.x, 0, lastPos.z);

            //Get target's position and rotates on y-axis
            Vector3 targetPosition = new Vector3(pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.x, 
                                                 this.transform.position.y, 
                                                 pathToFollow.pathObj[currentWayPointID - 1].position.z);
            this.transform.LookAt(targetPosition);

            if(distanceX <= reachDistance && distanceZ <= reachDistance)
                currentWayPointID--;
        }

        if(currentWayPointID >= pathToFollow.pathObj.Count)
        {
            //Put code to finish the level
            currentWayPointID = 6;
        }
        else if(currentWayPointID < 0)
            currentWayPointID = 0;
    }
}
```